# How can I customize the user dashboard?

Tags: user-dashboard

I'm talking about the user dashboard displayed for each contact who is logged in.  In wordpress this is displayed on a page using this shortcode: [civicrm component="user-dashboard" hijack="0"]

By default it displays (for the logged in user) Groups, Contributions, Events, Memberships,Related Contacts and Organizations.

I would like to display only the Groups and the Membership information, for example. Is there a way to customize this user dashboard?
(I'm using wordpress and civicrm 4.6.23)

Answer (score 11):

Under Administer - Custom Data and Screens - Display Preferences menu item there is a section for "Contact Dashboard"

You can turn on or off the display of Groups, Contributions, Memberships, Events, My Contacts/Organizations, Pledges, Personal Campaign Pages, Assigned Activities, Invoices / Credit Notes